# Unable to interpret 1 probability questions answer (beginner level)

Tags: probability

Note: I am unable to copy the text from my study material and thus attaching the corresponding snap.
[image]

I am unable to understand the statement where it says

> the P(A U B) is
>   least when B is a subset of A; in that case the P(A U B) is just the
>   P(A) which is 1/2

If B is a subset of A and if B event happens then A automatically happens (since A is a super-set of B); then how come the probability of P(A U B) is 1/2 instead of 1/3 (which is the probability of B). Since A is a superset of B then its not necessary that if A happens then B will also happen.

Edit: Hopefully you understand my question/confusion now.

Comment: Think of $\cup$ as "or" and $\cap$ as "and", that will do for a beginner level IMO.

Comment: That i understand, but it doesn't answer my question. Please read the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

Pure mathematically, If $B$ is a subset of $A$, then $A\cup B = A$. So, the probability is equal to $P(A)$.

Logically, $P(A \cup B)$ means that $P($ One of the Events in Set $A$ happened or One of the Events in set $B$ happened $)$. So, you seek for an event either in $A$ or $B$. And if the event set of $A$ captures all events that can be possible under label $B$, than actually you're seeking for event that belongs to set $A$, because you have an **or** statement embedded in $\cup$ sign.

Edit: Your image contains one more typo: for the max. value of $P(A \cup B)$, it sums $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ and obtain $\frac{5}{6}$. It's meant $\frac{1}{3}$ instead of $\frac{3}{4}$ there.

Comment: How is that incorrect ? Its mentioned clearly that A & B do not intersect so the probability of 2 events is the sum of their probabilities ? right ? which is 5/6. So why 1/3 of 3/4

Comment: The image sums $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{3}{4}$ and obtain $\frac{5}{6}$, I said this is wrong. Of course, it should be $\frac{1}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{3}$. Anyway, this is just another typo I realized in your image and does not relate to your question. Did you understand the answer to your question?

Comment: Yes its a typo. I understood your answer but i still don't get one sentence in the question i have posted. Read the quoted text where it says `the P(A U B) is least...` I understand now that P(AUB) is P(A) but if you want the least probability i.e the minimum chance of succeeding, then P(A) will be max chance of succeeding since it covers up A as well as B (as its a superset). Shouln't it be P(B) ?

Comment: First of all, you always have the following property: $P(A \cup B) \geq P(A)$ and $P(A \cup B) \geq P(B)$, in which you can merge the two with $P(A \cup B) \geq max(P(A),P(B))$, because sets $A$ and $B$ are both subsets of $A \cup B$. This is always true, independent of the question, values etc. So, you cannot have $P(A \cup B) = P(B)$ in this question.

Comment: Ok Thanks for that understanding. So what is the author intenting to explain when he says `the P(A U B) is least when B is a subset of A; in that case the P(A U B) is just the P(A) which is 1/2`. What does least mean here in the context ?

Comment: From that sentence , I understand that $P(A \cup B)$ is minimum when ...

Comment: when what ? please complete your statement.

Comment: the rest is the same as your sentence. “least” means minimum here. I don’t understand where you are stuck here.

Comment: What does minimum mean in the context above ? why is P(AUB) minimum probability ?

Comment: I don't have the question statement, but it appears that you're given probabilities of $A$ and $B$ events and you're asked the minimum and maximum values that $P(A \cup B)$ can take. And, in your case, minimum value of $P(A \cup B)$ is achieved when $B$ is a subset of $A$. This is what "P(A U B) is least when $B$ is a subset of $A$" means. For the maximum, as explained, you sum the probability of $A$ and $B$. Universally, you'll have the following inequality: $max(P(A),P(B)) \leq P(A \cup B) \leq P(A)+P(B)$